# Struts2: getText with multiple parameters not populating

Tags: java, struts2

I am passing in three parameters to getText but only the first one gets populated.

> getText("error.invalidcode", new String[] {"name", "age", "xyz"});

And in my ApplicationResources.properties

> error.invalidcode={0} and {1} property has error with code {2}.

I am getting the following result:
name and {1} property has error with code {2}.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening with field containing special characters.

```
error.missingfield={0}'s and {1} property has error with code {2}.
```

Had to escape by adding another single quote as:

```
error.invalidcode={0}''s and {1} property has error with code {2}.
```